# Why does this use of Smooth cause Python to crash?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using Python 2.6 against OpenCV 2.0.  I've started a file capture and pulled frames.  I've displayed the image to make sure it's valid.  When I call this routine, python crashes:

```
def SmoothImage(self,SmoothingMaskSize=3):
    temp=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(self._lpImage),self._lpImage.depth,self._lpImage.nChannels)
    cv.Smooth(self._lpImage,temp)
    self._lpImage=temp
```

I've also tried smoothing it in-place, using cv.Smooth(self._lpImage, self._lpImage)

I'm new to Python- am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: If you post up the error message I can probably help you :)

Comment: unrelated to your question and problem. You are using c# naming style, which is not the preferred python naming style. see PEP-8 for python naming style.

Comment: Whoops- the error is:
pythonw.exe 
0.0.0.0 
4ae54f49 
libcv200.dll 
c0000005 
c0005acfc 

As I said, I'm new to Python and completely ignorant of naming styles :) Thanks for the info though, I'll look up PEP-8.

Comment: Taking a look at that error:
pythonw.exe
0.0.0.0
4ae54f49
libcv200.dll
c0000005
c0005acfc

It seems like the binding parameters are mismatched between Python and the DLL.  Is it a typing issue?  In cv.py, cvSmooth passes through to the PYD, which, from scanning the file, links to cvSmooth in OpenCV.  cvSmooth is declared:

cvSmooth( const void* srcarr, void* dstarr, int smooth_type,
          int param1, int param2, double param3, double param4 )

Why would this particular function fail when other OpenCV functions with the same pointer parameters work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bindings that come with the OpenCV 2.0 installer are buggy; I had similar problem where some very simple operations triggered crashes. Compiling from the source should fix it.

Comment: Thanks Johannes!  I pulled the source from SVN and re-compiled.  Despite checking it in CMake, the python support was not compiled, but once I did that manually, everything was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need access to the object-oriented parts of OpenCV, you should take a look at ctypes-opencv, which is a better set of python bindings. It is lovingly hand-crafted, in contrast to the SWIG-generated bindings that come with OpenCV, and I have never found any bugs in it.

http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

Can you isolate the problem by removing the class definition? I get this working:

```
planes = [cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(image), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 1) for i in range(3)]
cv.Split(image, planes[0], planes[1], planes[2], None)
for plane in planes:
    cv.Smooth(plane, plane, smoothtype=cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, param1=9, param2=0, param3=0, param4=0)
```